# Why is parameter in callback function optional?

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback

If you omit a parameter to a callback function, it still works. For example,

```
var callback1 = function() {
    $("span").prepend("Callback 1: " +  event.pageX + " " + event.pageY + "<br>");
};
$("div").click(callback1);
```

works when the `event` parameter is not passed. It seems equivalent to:

```
var callback2 = function(event) {
    $("span").prepend("Callback 2: " +  event.pageX + " " + event.pageY + "<br>");
};
$("div").click(callback2);
```

with the parameter passed as I feel it should be.

Working JSFiddle of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4oq5papv/).

---

I found this JS phenomenon peculiar. Why does it work?

Comment: It **only** works when you're referring to `event`, and it really isn't working in your example because `event` refers to the browser's version, not the augmented/normalized jQuery Event instance.

Comment: Because Internet Explorer compatibility. It *should* not work…

Comment: Oh, and it does not work in Firefox.

Comment: @Bergi But it doesn't only happen with `event`. It happens with other variables as well.

Comment: @JonathanLam: That I doubt. Which ones specifically? Of course, there are many global variables that have *some* values; but no - a function doesn't magically make undeclared variables become parameters.

Comment: @Bergi I'll post an example.

Comment: Your `print` function has that `data` parameter declared. Make it `function print() { … }` and it will stop working.

Comment: @Bergi Oops. I thought it didn't never mind, and thanks for your time.